# Why does my subscription stops working after subscribing to exactly six new values?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, rxjs, observable

I have a posts.component. In the **posts.component.html**, I have the following

```
<ngx-masonry  class="masonry" [options]="myOptions" [updateLayout]="hasPostOpened">
  <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonryItem" *ngFor="let post of posts;index as idx" (click)="showPostDetail(post)" >
    <div class="crop">{{post.description}}</div>
    <img [src]="imgConstructor(post.img)">
  </div>
  <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonryItem masonryUser" *ngFor="let user of usersToDisplay" (click)="navigateToProfile(user.id)" >
    <img [src]="userImgConstructor(user.profileImage)">
    <div class="crop-user">{{user.username}}</div>
  </div>
</ngx-masonry>
</div>

<div class="detail" *ngIf="hasPostOpened">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The function **showPostDetail(post)** is defined as follows:

```
showPostDetail(post) {
  this.sharedSrv.getHasPostOpened().subscribe(hasOpened => {
    if(hasPostOpened)
    this.router.navigate(['/post-detail/' + post.id]);
    else {
      this.sharedSrv.setHasPostOpened(true);
     this.router.navigate(['/post-detail/' + post.id]);

    }
  })
  
}
```

Because I do not rerender the **post-detail.component**, I pass the id of the post to the route and subscribe to the route in the **post-detail.component**, so I can get the id of the post and construct the new view for the new post:

```
async ngOnInit(){
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(async params => {
      this.waitUntilDataLoaded = false;
      this.subComments = [];
      this.post = {}
      let post_id = params.get('id');
      await this.publicSrv.getSinglePost(post_id).toPromise().then(post => {
        this.post = post;
        console.log(post);
      })
      await this.publicSrv.getCommentsFromPost(post_id).toPromise().then(async mainComments => {
        this.mainComments = mainComments;
        for(let mainComment of this.mainComments){
          this.subComments.push(await this.publicSrv.getSubComments(this.post.id, mainComment.commentator_id, mainComment.id).toPromise())
        }})

       this.waitUntilDataLoaded = true;
    })
}
```

I can open exactly 6 posts correctly and if I try to open a seventh post, the subscription stops working everytime. Why does the subscription always stops working after 6 posts opened in detail-view?

EDIT:

**getSinglePost()**

```
getSinglePost(p_id){
    return this.http.get(this.publicUrl + 'get/single-post', {params: {p_id: p_id}});
  }
```

**getSubComments()**

```
getSubComments(p_id, commentator_id, row_id){
    return this.http.get(this.publicUrl + "get/sub-comments", {params: {p_id: p_id, commentator_id: commentator_id, row_id: row_id}});
  }
```

**getCommentsFromPost()**

```
getCommentsFromPost(p_id){
    return this.http.get(this.publicUrl + "get/main-comments", {params: {p_id: p_id}})
  }
```

Comment: does it stop working like if it's an error or does the observable completes ?

Comment: @Elmehdi There is no error, but you can see that I console log the post but nothing appears on the console. Like, the new id was not passed correctly although the url changes

Comment: Please post the code for your `this.publicSrv` functions. `getSingePost`, `getCommentsFromPost`, `getSubComments`.

Comment: @fridoo Hey, I posted the code for the functions you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you wrap your subscription like this:

```
async ngOnInit(){
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe({
     next: async params => {
      this.waitUntilDataLoaded = false;
      this.subComments = [];
      this.post = {}
      let post_id = params.get('id');
      await this.publicSrv.getSingePost(post_id).toPromise().then(post => {
        this.post = post;
        console.log(post);
      })
      await this.publicSrv.getCommentsFromPost(post_id).toPromise().then(async mainComments => {
        this.mainComments = mainComments;
        for(let mainComment of this.mainComments){
          this.subComments.push(await this.publicSrv.getSubComments(this.post.id, mainComment.commentator_id, mainComment.id).toPromise())
        }})

       this.waitUntilDataLoaded = true;
    }),
     complete: () => console.log('completed')
   }
}
```

if it prints 'completed' in the console it will mean that the observable completes.
I may have made a type so to make sure it should follow the template below:

```
  .subscribe({
    next: // your usual subscription function,
    complete: () => console.log('completed')
  })
```

Comment: Hey, I tried it but nothing happened. So the observable did not complete but the subscription stops after six times

Comment: can you add an error function in the subscription like so:
error: (err) => console.log(err),
there must be at least an error thrown, if not you will have check out this.route.paramMap

Comment: No error, then it has to be this.route.paramMap. I think I have to overthink how I want to do this.